# Laravel hasMany Relationship error Undefined property

Tags: laravel

I am trying to return all media that I have linked to a device via the database. I had this working in an older version of laravel but now on the most recent verion I have copied and pasted the code over and I am getting an error.

I run a schedule and each schedule has media linked to it.

Model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Schedule extends Model
{
    //
    public function scheduled_media(){

        return $this->hasMany('App\ScheduledMedia');

    }
}
```

Blade:

```
@foreach($schedule->scheduled_media as $m))
    {{$m->name}}
@endforeach
```

Error:

> Undefined property: stdClass::$scheduled_media (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\displaycontroller\resources\views\sites\showdisplay.blade.php)

I am lost as I don't understand why it's saying that it is an undefined property when I have it written in the Model as you can see above.

Comment: Adding last and current used version of Laravel could help.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. It was the way I was getting my data in the controller using raw. By changing to Schedule::all() it worked.

Comment: You can add with('scheduled_media') and will get the same results

Comment: use with just like buglinjo mentioned or else you will prbably face the n+1 probleme